# why I can't use var value in my button action?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want value send to my button...

why I can't use quizWord in my button action??

it occurs "use of unsolved identifier..." error...

```
    import UIKit

extension Array
{
    /** Randomizes the order of an array's elements. */
    mutating func shuffle()
    {
        for _ in 0..<10
        {
            sort { (_,_) in arc4random() < arc4random() }
        }
    }
}
// random




class QuizViewController: UIViewController {



    var tasks : [Task] = []
    var limitRe:Int = 0
    var cards: [Character] = []
    var quizName = [String]()
    var quizfileName = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //get the data from core data
        getData()

        for q in 0...tasks.count-1 {
            let quiz = tasks[q]
            quizName.append(quiz.name!)
            quizfileName.append(quiz.filename!)
            print(quizName, quizfileName)
        }
        var quizWord = quizName[0]
        var countText: Int = (quizWord.characters.count) - 1

        for _ in 0...countText
        {let index1 = quizWord.index(quizWord.startIndex, offsetBy: limitRe)

            cards.append(quizWord[index1])
            limitRe = limitRe + 1
        }
        cards.shuffle()
        quizPhotoView.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")

        if countText >= 0 {lblChar1.text = "\(cards[0])"} else {lblChar1.text = ""}
        if countText >= 1 {lblChar2.text = "\(cards[1])"} else {lblChar2.text = ""}
        if countText >= 2 {lblChar3.text = "\(cards[2])"} else {lblChar3.text = ""}
        if countText >= 3 {lblChar4.text = "\(cards[3])"} else {lblChar4.text = ""}
        if countText >= 4 {lblChar5.text = "\(cards[4])"} else {lblChar5.text = ""}
        if countText >= 5 {lblChar6.text = "\(cards[5])"} else {lblChar6.text = ""}
        if countText >= 6 {lblChar7.text = "\(cards[6])"} else {lblChar7.text = ""}
        if countText >= 7 {lblChar8.text = "\(cards[7])"} else {lblChar8.text = ""}

    }



    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar6: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar7: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblChar8: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTyped: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var quizPhotoView: UIImageView!


    func getData() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {
            tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }


    @IBAction func butChar1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar1.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}}
    @IBAction func butChar2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar2.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}
    }
    @IBAction func butChar3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar3.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}}
    @IBAction func butChar4(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar4.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}}
    @IBAction func butChar5(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar5.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}}
    @IBAction func butChar6(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar6.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}}
    @IBAction func butChar7(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar7.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}}
    @IBAction func butChar8(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (lblTyped.text!.characters.count) > (quizWord.characters.count) - 1 {lblTyped.text = ""}
        lblTyped.text = lblTyped.text! + lblChar8.text!
        if lblTyped.text == quizWord {lblTyped.text = "Good"}}

}
```

Comment: add quizWord outside the viewDidLoad with other class variables like quizfileName.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have declared `quizWord` inside `ViewDidLoad` so it is a local variable which will only be available inside `ViewDidLoad` function.

If you want `quizWord` to be used through out the viewController `QuizViewController` then you have to declare it outside all functions just like you did for `quizfileName`,`quizName` etc.
May be like

```
   var quizfileName = [String]()
   var quizWord:String?
```

Comment: I used core data...outside of viewdidload, I can't run getData() func...

Comment: Core data has nothing to deal with the variable's scope

Answer (score 0):

Due to local scope of variable you can use in only `viewDidLoad()` method you need to declare as top of class not in `viewDidLoad()` method

```
class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

var quizWord  : String = ""

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overview your code there is problem with you quizWord string variable just declare the variable outside viewDidLoad() function

eg.

```
var tasks : [Task] = []
var limitRe:Int = 0
var cards: [Character] = []
var quizName = [String]()
var quizfileName = [String]()
**var quizWord  : String = ""**
```

and you good to go 
Thanks